# Adaptive Lagrangian-Eulerian methods and practical benchmark results

Tags: finite-element, reference-request

Does anyone know of any published study that talks about the practical aspects of running Adaptive Lagrangian-Eulerian techniques for solid and/or fluid mechanics problems?

I'm looking for things like benchmark results when doing a run weighted towards a more Eulerian grid than a Lagrangian grid or vice versa, mesh resolution considerations, etc. For example, a more Eulerian run would have more advection error but how much can that error be reduced with increased mesh resolution.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the papers that came out of the early stages of the MoFEM package considered these sorts of questions. You might want to look at their results.